# How do I Execute Visual Basic Exe and Crystal report in LAN

Tags: vba, crystal-reports, vb6

Hi I have a Visual Basic Project Exe which runs fine on a Single Machine i Want it to be Execute for Multi User in LAN. I Have Used Crystal Reports in My Project and database is MS Acess. Please Help me how run the Project in LAN..

Answer (score 0):

A VB EXE is a client architecture which usually needs installing on each client machine using it. The code in the EXE could/would normally then connect to external shared, singular resources over a network (such as databases, reporting servers etc.) but the actual EXE itself would typically be duplicated upon each client computer.

If you need all the users to open the exe and have it always run on the same machine, then you *could* create client shortcuts or use a script with a CreateObject("application.NameHere","serverToRunAppOn") call &/or modify the DCOM settings for the app through the dcomcnfg tool...

However I'd sugguest instead re-evaluating your architecture. Possibly turning your app into a better practice web-based or MS Access shared MDE+MDB solution for clients to connect to.